# Evince - printing a pdf with a wrong page-size

Tags: printing, evince

Whenever I print a PDF file from evince, and the PDF page size is different from my printer's page size (e.g. Letter file on A4 printer), the printer emits a blank page. Is there a fix or a workaround?

Comment: You mean, only a blank page?

Comment: @vanadium yes, only a blank page. Nothing is printed.